# ASP.NET webforms - is meta:resourcekey unique or can we create our own metas?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The subject pretty much says it all. How does the `meta:resourcekey` attribute work, and can we create our own `meta:stackoverflow` tags with whatever functionality we desire?

Comment: Removed the meta tag because a lot of people have it set as an ignored tag: no one was seeing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blah. Turns out these prefixes are for [device filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/library/ms178620(en-us).aspx). And `meta:resourcekey` is special. :P